# Ability to filter your questions by unanswered or not chosen

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering

I have a lot of questions and I really like to give approval to all of them to ensure I am giving feedback to the people answering and not have any lingering questions.

Is there anyway to filter my questions to just see the one that don't have an answer selected? This will save me time instead of just scrolling through all questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the site search box:

> user:me hasaccepted:0

Will search only your questions and only show those that do not have an accepted answer.

Comment: Have you collected the search box questions before answering them in a row?

Comment: Probably should have done that instead of stumbling across them. Would have been more waterfallic.